# angular2 rc3 router alpha 3.0.0.7 default route

Tags: angular, router

angular2 rc3...Using the new router (alpha 3.0.0-alpha.7), how do i specify a default route? useAsDefault is the old router...and '*' doesn't seem to work.

this shoud make it clear what i want...i cannot get the "NotFoundComponent" part working.

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: 'abc', component: AbcComponent },
    { path: 'def', component: DefComponent },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '*', component: NotFoundComponent }  // something like this
];
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it should be

`{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }`

Here is the [doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterConfig-type-alias.html#!#wild-cards)

BTW,

There is a way if you want to set root to default route.

Set pathMatch = 'full' and set redirectTo value

```
[
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'teams'
  },
  {
    path: 'teams',
    component: TeamsComponent
  }
]
```

Here is the [blog post](http://victorsavkin.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes) talking about this