# Cannot match any routes: '' NativeScript, TypeScript and Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm working on an app in NativeScript 2.1.0 and TypeScript 1.8.10 with Angular2 rc3 using the new angular router version 3.0.0-alpha.7. I'm trying to use page-router-outlet but I'm getting errors. I'm currently compiling and testing in Android 5.1.1 in an emulator on Windows. The app did run once for me but even then I had the `Cannot match any routes: ''` error. I changed something (not sure what) but now when it runs I see only a blank page, which my be my PageNavigationApp component below. My intention is to have access to Page 1 and Page 2 but I guess I'm not understanding the role of my page-router-outlet component. That aside, I'm seeing lots of errors when the app runs.

Here's the code in my main.ts file:

```js
import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from 'nativescript-angular/application';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';
import {NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, nsProvideRouter} from 'nativescript-angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'nav',
    directives: [NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`
})
export class PageNavigationApp { 
}

@Component({
    selector: "first",
    directives: [NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
    <StackLayout>
        <Label text="First component" class="title"></Label>
        <Button text="GO TO SECOND" [nsRouterLink]="['/second']" class="link"></Button>
    </StackLayout>`
})
export class FirstComponent { }

@Component({
    selector: "second",
    directives: [NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
    <StackLayout>
        <Label text="Second component" class="title"></Label>
        <Button text="GO TO FIRST" [nsRouterLink]="['/first']" class="link"></Button>
    </StackLayout>`
})
export class SecondComponent { }

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    /*{path: "", redirectTo: "/first", terminal: true },*/
    {path: "nav", component: PageNavigationApp},
    {path: "first", component: FirstComponent},
    {path: "second", component: SecondComponent}
]

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    nsProvideRouter(routes, {enableTracing: false})
]

nativeScriptBootstrap(PageNavigationApp, [APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

The errors I'm getting are Cannot match any routes: '' and Cannot read property 'visitExpression' of undefined.

I found this post on SO Concerning default routes and I changed my code to match (I think anyway). See below.
[angular2 rc3 router alpha 3.0.0.7 default route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110453/angular2-rc3-router-alpha-3-0-0-7-default-route)

**EDIT**

I've changed my code to the following but I'm getting the visitExpression error:

```
...

@Component({
    selector: 'nav',
    directives: [NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`
})

...

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/first', terminal: false },
    {path: 'first', component: FirstComponent},
    {path: 'second', component: SecondComponent}
]
```

The new error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 
'visitExpression' of undefined at resolvePromise
(/data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/
zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:496:32)
```

Comment: Hey, not sure if it helps but I just upgraded the master branch of https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries to ng2 RC3 and the new router and it’s running so far. That being said, the big difference is I’m not using Firebase (yet), but I thought you still might find it an interesting reference.

Comment: @TJVanToll Thanks for the update TJ. I'm not using Firebase either, but I'm going to review the Groceries App and see if I can spot any differences. I think for one thing that you aren't using page-router-outlet on Groceries.

Comment: I've tested your code on my ios simulator and worked great. Check your package.json with the https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ng to see if your packages are up to date.

Comment: Also, make sure you have terminal: true, not false

Comment: @HK1: fyi I am using <page-router-outlet> in Groceries. See https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/c4eb98f23a13eca8433eb23d6190bc301b1bd888/app/app.component.ts#L8.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you didn't set a default page for the router. In the router config you should add  `useAsDefault: true` onto the route that you want to have show up first.

Comment: I think that's a valid property only in the the deprecated angular router. I get a red underline in Visual Studio Code when I add this to my routes. See Angular's documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: You already have the code for the default route for the new router (the commented out route for `path: ""`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So do you always use "" for default route? And does that need to correspond to a Component with a Selector of ""?

Comment: Either `forwardTo` or `component`, and yes, always